# ArrayList in a class of type structure is populate with constructor the form first instantiates it but having trouble with for each statement to read

Tags: .net, visual-studio, for-loop, collections

Public Class Expense

' I have a public structure and ArrayList collection in my Expense Class.

```
Public Structure ExpAmortize
Public aAmor = New ArrayList()
```

The constructor calls a function the when instantiated populates the ArrayList with many of the structures.  This all works great and I have checked the values using a watchlists.  So when the Form is loaded it instantiates my class clsHouse (class Expense).  On the Form I have a listbox that I want to write all the data to as a check.

My issue is figuring out how to get a valid For Each loop - I have been trying a verity of ways here was the latest:

```
    'loop through all ExpAmor
    For Each clsHouse.ExpAmortize In clsHouse.aAmor
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("I am here")
    Next
```

Error: Expense.ExpAmortize is a structure type and cannot be used as an expression

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OMG  - I was overthinking it.

```
    'loop through all ExpAmor
    For Each item In clsHouse.aAmor
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("I am here")
    Next
```